# how can iPhone work as usb device?

Tags: iphone

I notice that there some apps make iPhone become a remote mouse or udisk.
I guess it change iPhone into a usb device.

but I really hope to know the mechanism of these app.

Is there any sample code to help me to understand?

Thanks

interdev

Comment: There are apps that let you control a mouse cursor or store files, but I've only seen network-based apps (using VNC/RDC or SSH/SMB/FTP, respectively). Also, Apple has been rejecting apps that directly access the USB port as a device (as opposed to controller mode with the external device APIs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These generally work over WiFi, when the computer and phone are on the same network.